# Set dimensions (number lines) of JTextArea (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing

Here's a code of a silly application for data entry. I would like that the "oggetto" JTextArea to have a size so that the user can enter different lines of information:

```
JPanel body = new JPanel();
body.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
body.add(new JLabel("Inserimento di un nuovo protocollo"));

JTextArea oggetto = new JTextArea(5,1);
oggetto.setOpaque(true);
oggetto.setBackground(Color.cyan);
//oggetto.setSize(100, 100);

...
body.add(oggetto);
jframe.add(body);
jframe.setVisible(true);
```

I've tried many ways to make it but when I launch the app I only get a "oggetto" jtextarea of a unique line...
can you help me?

Comment: Please explain a bit. Not clear what you want to try?

Comment: Sorry...I mean that I want the oggetto JTextArea to have a certain height...so that the user can enter and read two or more lines of data. Now It displays me only a line, like the picture below: http://uploadpie.com/VMpNu

Comment: The size of `oggetto` will be the same size as the largest component added to the `GridLayout` since it makes all components the same size.   For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

            JPanel body = new JPanel();
            body.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
            c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c1.weightx = 1.0;// 100%
            c1.gridx = 0;// column 0
            c1.gridy = 0;// row 0
            body.add(new JLabel("Inserimento di un nuovo protocollo"), c1);

            JTextArea oggetto = new JTextArea(5,1);
            oggetto.setOpaque(true);
            oggetto.setBackground(Color.cyan);

            GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
            c2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c2.weightx = 1.0; // 100%
            c2.gridx = 0; // column 0
            c2.gridy = 1; // row 1

            body.add(oggetto, c2);
            frame.add(body);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
```

I recommend to use [TableLayout](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html) since it the best layout to understand and to implement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

    JPanel body = new JPanel();

    double[][] dim = {
            {20, TableLayout.FILL, 20}, // column widths: 20 distance right/left, TableLayout.FILL usable place
            {20, 17, 5, TableLayout.FILL, 20}  // row height: 20 distance up/down, 17 place for label, 5 distance between label-textarea
            };

    body.setLayout(new TableLayout(dim));

    JTextArea oggetto = new JTextArea(5,1);
    oggetto.setOpaque(true);
    oggetto.setBackground(Color.cyan);


    body.add(new JLabel("Inserimento di un nuovo protocollo"), "1,1"); // col: 1, row: 1
    body.add(oggetto, "1,3");// col: 1(TableLayout.FILL), row: 3 (TableLayout.FILL)
    frame.add(body);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

For more components to add define "dim" like this example shows:

```
double[][] dim = {
            {20, TableLayout.FILL, 20},
            {20, 17, 5, TableLayout.FILL /*label1,distance,component1*/, 17, 5, TableLayout.FILL/*label2,distance,component2 etc...*/, 20} 
    };
```

Comment: Why is, what you recommending and what you portrayed in this code, doesn't coincides?

Comment: @LoryLory look at my TableLayout example.

Comment: @dit Thanks, I think i've made it work. I'd have another question to put to you: how can I do so that all words are contained inside the text area? I mean that, unless I put the ENTER key, words keep on being written all in a single line and they are hidden by the border of the text area. I would like that when the border of the text area is reached, then a new line should be started. Can you help me?

Comment: @LoryLory just use oggetto.setLineWrap(true);

Comment: @dit I've become familiar with TableLayout and now I'd need to know the following: how can I initialize the array double[][] dim if I know the number of columns or rows only at runtime? For example I need to print a list of objects, books. I'd need only a column and as many rows as the list of book size. how can I do?

Comment: double[][] arr = new double[1][list.size()]; and then init using for each loop

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use another layout such as [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) or [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) or [others](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) that suits here.

Using `GridBagLayout` you can give the components size in *percentage* along horizontally and vertically.

Read more about [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

**Note:** Never call `setSize()` for the components and leave it for Layout Manager to decide the size and position of the component.

Read more [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

---

Sample code (using `GridBagLayout`)

```
JPanel body = new JPanel();
body.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
gc.fill = GridBagConstants.BOTH;
gc.weightx = 1.0; // 100%

gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 0;
gc.weighty = 0.1;// 10%
body.add(new JLabel("Inserimento di un nuovo protocollo"), gc);

JTextArea oggetto = new JTextArea(5, 1);
oggetto.setOpaque(true);
oggetto.setRows(10);
oggetto.setBackground(Color.cyan);

gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 1;
gc.weighty = 0.9; // 90%
body.add(oggetto, gc);
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with the layout you have chosen. Because [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) divides your component into equal size blocks:

> The GridLayout class is a layout manager that lays out a container's
>   components in a rectangular grid. The container is divided into
>   equal-sized rectangles, and one component is placed in each rectangle.

You should use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) for more flexibility.